# firebase cloud function fails to access storage bucket

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

i'm trying to handle uploaded file using cloud function in firebase but it fails with the error :

```
Error parsing countries.json: TypeError: getStorage(...).bucket is not a function
```

and here is how my function looks like :

```
exports.handleFiles = onObjectFinalized({

  bucket: //mybucketnamehere,
  timeoutSeconds: 540,
  memory: "1GiB",
}, async (event) => {
  // Get the file name and bucket name
  const filePath = event.data.name;
  //   const fileName = filePath.split("/").pop();

  if (filePath.includes("countries")) {
    // Get reference to the file in Firebase Cloud Storage
    try {
      // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
      const fileBucket = event.data.bucket; // Storage bucket containing the file.

      const bucket = getStorage().bucket(fileBucket);
      const downloadResponse = await bucket.file(filePath).download();
      const fileContent = downloadResponse[0];

      // Download the file

      // Parse the JSON content
      const countriesData = JSON.parse(fileContent.toString());
      // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
      const filePath = event.data.name;
      // Delete all documents in the "countries" collection
      await db.collection("countries").get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          doc.ref.delete();
        });
      });
      // Do something with the parsed data
      // Create new documents for every feature
      for (const item of countriesData.features) {
        await db.collection("countries").add({
          name_en: item.properties.name_en,
          name_ar: item.properties.name_ar,
          file_id: item.properties.file_id,
          title_ar: item.properties.title_ar,
          title_en: item.properties.title_en,
          object_id: item.properties.OBJECTID,
          file_url: filePath,
        });
      }

      // Here you can perform further processing with the parsed data

      return null;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error parsing countries.json:", error);
      return null;
    }
  }
});
```

i think the error is in the line `const bucket = getStorage().bucket(fileBucket);` where am trying to access the uploaded file

Comment: * Can you make sure of the API version you are using? * The value of the bucket's name should be encapsulated with quotes, can you do it and make sure you can access it? * I see you are already using the code from the documentation, so you shouldn't have an issue if you follow the doc in the required way. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions?gen=2nd#download-transform